# Custom view, onSaveInstanceState is not called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-custom-view

I created a custom view, and tried to restore the state automatically on screen rotation (just as `EditText` restores current input text automatically), but when I see the log, `onSaveInstanceState` is not called, and only `onRestoreInstanceState` is called. What is wrong?

```
class MyView:LinearLayout
{
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
            context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    init
    {
        isSaveEnabled=true
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable
    {
        return super.onSaveInstanceState()
        Log.d("ss", "save")
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
        Log.d("ss", "restore")
    }
}
```

Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.loser.mylayouttest.MyView
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the scenario you've tried to see `onSaveInstanceState()` get called?

Comment: Screen rotation.

Comment: Isn't `AbsoluteLayout` deprecated since API 3? Try `FrameLayout` -- and put the Log statement above the return

Comment: You are right. I did not notice the automatically inserted "return" super call. I know AbsoluteLayout is deprecated, but I just wanted the simplest thing for this example (this is not the actual project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can't see `Log.d("ss", "save")` being called is simply that the code line is invoked after the `return` statement. The `onSaveInstanceState()` is actually called. To see the log move `Log.d("ss", "save")` above `return super.onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: So OP should call the log before of return super

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. The super call was automatically inserted by the IDE so I did not notice that it was a return statement.